# Change Listview Adapter Row Based on NickName android

Tags: android, android-listview

In my listViewAdapter if the nickname is dexter, the listview row vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sujet_ro, null); is shown on the screen else if nickName not equals to dexter another row is shown. This is shown in my code below. When i run the code, if the name is not dexter it opens in the if condition and never goes to else. What have i done or miss please help.

```
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;

            player = data.get(position).getPlayer();

            try {

                jsonObject = new JSONObject(player);

                if (jsonObject.has("@nickName"))
                    nickName = jsonObject.getString("@nickName");

                //System.out.println("nickName: "+ nickName);



            }catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        if (convertView == null) {

                if (nickName.equalsIgnoreCase("dexter")) {
                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sujet_ro, null);

                    System.out.println("nickName: "+ "dexter");

                } else {

                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_droite, null);
                    System.out.println("nickName: "+ "mckay");
                }


    holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.txMessage = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txMessage);
                holder.txLeft= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txLeft);
                holder.txRight=  (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txRight);


                vi.setTag(holder);


    }else{

                holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`convertView` returns `null` first time call to `getView()` otherwise it will return already inflated layouts view but your requirement is need to change layout depends on some data so that you need to inflate layout every time like below i mentioned. I don't know how to use viewholder for this type of requirement.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = null;
        player = data.get(position).getPlayer();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(player);
            if (jsonObject.has("@nickName"))
                nickName = jsonObject.getString("@nickName");
                //System.out.println("nickName: "+ nickName);
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                
        if (nickName.equalsIgnoreCase("dexter")) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sujet_ro, null);
            System.out.println("nickName: "+ "dexter");
        } else {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_droite, null);
            System.out.println("nickName: "+ "mckay");
        }
        // Note: Before accessing your textviews try to check whether both layouts has same textview with below id
        //(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txMessage);
        //(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txLeft);
        //(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txRight);
```